# inference return type based on arguments

Tags: typescript

I am trying to infer the return type based on given arguments

Ive tried using generics.

```
type Getter<T> = T extends string ? string : object

function get<T> (key?: T ): Getter<T|undefined> {
    if (key) {
        return 'string'
    } else {
        return {} 
    }
}

let single = get('htewr')
let multi = get()
```

`multi` is alrdy inferring that it must be of object type. However `single` still infers that it is of `string | object` type instead of just string type.

Comment: Overloading would probably solve this. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into the distributive behavior of conditional types. `Getter<T | undefined> = Getter<T> | Getter<undefined> = Getter<T> | object` So regardless of `T` you will get an `object` in the resuting union.

This works as expected:

```
type Getter<T> = T extends string ? string : object

function get<T> (key?: T): Getter<T> {
    if (key) {
        return 'string' as Getter<T>
    } else {
        return {} as Getter<T>
    }
}

let single = get('htewr') // string 
let multi = get() // object
```